# https on tmobile android super slow (using httpclient.execute method)

Tags: android, ssl, mobile, https, httpclient

I have an application that makes numerous calls to REST web services I have written.   I have noticed in general that when I added SSL the web calls went from <1 sec to ~3sec to execute.   Is that normal when adding SSL?   I have measured the times using the Droid, HTC Thunderbolt, and Samsung Tablet (all on Verizon).

What is really CRAZY is:
whenever using a phone on the TMobile network (Comet and Nexus) those same calls (over HTTPs) take 30-40 seconds each.   If I remove SSL those same calls take <1s just like the other devices.   Any clue as to why SSL on the TMobile devices is having this issues?   I am stumped?

Code:

```
    String url = BASE_URL + path;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(30000));
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter("setSocketBufferSize", 8192);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
    InputStream istream = null;

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(request.toString()));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        istream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String result = IOUtils.toString(istream);
    ...
```

Comment: Due to it's processing power, any mobile device may have issues with HTTPS. HTTPS protocol is much more expensive than "traditional" HTTP.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue because if I put the Comet and Nexus on my wifi network the time to process the HTTPS web calls is then the same as the other devices (~3 seconds).   So, it is clearly only when on the TMobile network that it takes 30-40 seconds.

Comment: You can not compare Wifi (WLAN) with GPRS/UMTS. The latency in a UMTS network is about 500msec and worse; WLAN is much faster. This has a big impact on the SSL/TLS handshake time.

Comment: My question is why does a HTTPS call on the Sprint, Verizon, or AT&T network take 3 seconds, but on the TMobile Comet or Nexus it take 30-40 seconds?